# How does tagging work in sage maker studio. Does the tags applied to users propagate to the resources created in studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

In sage maker studio, How can we apply tags to the resources which are created by the user inside the studio.
As per my knowledge, Tags can be applied to the users created under the domain. Does these tags automatically propagate to notebooks created in studio.
Where can these tags be viewed.

Answer (score 0):

The tags applied to user profiles are automatically propagated to the 'apps' the user creates (that run the notebooks).

You can use the [ListTags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_ListTags.html) API to view tags for any SageMaker resource. CLI documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker/list-tags.html).

Note: For resources such as SageMaker Training jobs, Processing jobs etc. that are created from the notebooks, you'll have to manually tag them.